# `d` for what in d.strftime(fmt)?

Tags: python

In Django's strftime() and strptime() Behavior
[8.1. datetime — Basic date and time types — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

> date, datetime, and time objects all support a strftime(format) method, to create a string representing the time under the control of an explicit format string. Broadly speaking, d.strftime(fmt) acts like the time module’s time.strftime(fmt, d.timetuple()) although not all objects support a timetuple() method.

Amongst the paragraph, what's `d` for in `d.strftime(fmt)`? 
Abbreviation for `date` and `datetime`?
It does not make sense, 
because there are 3 objects specified at the starting of the paragraph.

Comment: `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: Report here: https://docs.python.org/3/bugs.html

Comment: It's just a variable containing datetime, date or time object.

Comment: It says "date, datetime, and time objects all support a strftime(format) method". So it is a container variable for datetime, date or time as @zipa stated.

Comment: "It does not make sense, because there are 3 objects specified at the starting of the paragraph." It does, because it also states that _all of them_ have that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider `d` here as a datetime instance. And `strftime` is a method of datetime instance which formats date to a given `fmt` format pattern.

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.now()
d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S.%f %p") # returns '11/07/2017 01:23:33.045843 PM'
d.strftime("%s") # returns string with amount of seconds since epoch
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation for the datetime module; `strftime` is a method that - as that quote states - is available on all three of the classes in that module.

`d` is just a name for the instance that you are calling the method on; it could be one of any of those types.